# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Will you please tell me what is wrong about this code !!!

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Profile <span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am also including this within my html file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When i click the dropdown menu it is not functioning at all , please i need help.

Comment: Your "bootstrap.min.js" file is not correctly linked. You are missing the closing ">"

Comment: Correct , But it is correctly typed on my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jquery call should come first.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

also, you forgot the close tag on the bootstrap call.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                                                                 ˆ
```

Comment: Thanks , I changed the order of files and it is functioning pretty well now :)

Comment: Good catch @EduRuiz

Comment: @wfareed you are welcome, please click in "accept answer". Is good for the community and for my reputation :D

Comment: @HanletEscaño thanks! :) This is the kind of stuff that happens sometimes and we spend hours trying to solve to find that the problem is a typo.